# WebRTC make a connection between two different devices

Tags: webrtc

Well I am studying about Web-RTC from its official [documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0). I need to integrate live streaming in my website but after seeing this and studying about all its documentation. I only learn about streaming on locally like on same browser and same page. But this is not what i want. I want to start stream from my admin panel(This part has been completed) and broadcast that stream whoever has access to my website whatever the website is and whatever device. Whoever open my website if i m streaming then he should see that and if some of u have worked on live streaming then u should tell me. It will be a great help for me. All i did until now is to make a connection between two peers on same page. Now i want to make global peer to peer connection

Comment: which server you are using ??

Comment: I have my own domain

Comment: [link](https://sistemasintegradosao.com/videoStreaming/step-02/)

Comment: This is is link what i did here]

Comment: Please if u know anythig about it or if u have worked on it then please tell me... I badly need help... I haven't worked on this techology before

Comment: So basically you are using  webRTC on one page try to use the over the server

Comment: yes actually i want to make a live stream on my website so that my viewers can see that..wherever they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this implementation using [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer). Basically a wrapper for webRTC.

As soon as a new user connects a new webrtc connection should be made between the receiver and the caller. The receiver is firstly initialized and then sends a message to the sender to start the connection. This first connection is all done by your own server you should write.

[Here is a working example](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer). And here is the [demo](http://dirvann-webrtc-video.herokuapp.com/). Any connected devices will be automatically connected to the call. Multiple users supported. You'll find all the webrtc code in `/public/js/main.js`

Comment: how will the user will join the room

Comment: is there not any password or vode to join the rrom?

Comment: Thanks a lot i works perfectly what i wanted but i still have few questions should we start in chat room?

Comment: In this example code no rooms have been implemented yet. But you can start with this code and work further on that. To implement rooms you could add a parameter to the url. And the backend puts all the sockets of a specific room id together. Then instead of sending signals to everyone. Only a signal to the same room is sent.

Comment: @QaissAria come join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213436/webrtc-multi-user

Comment: well i have some questions

Comment: can u guide in makign rooms?

Comment: @QaissAria there you go

Comment: Please come in chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213442/discussion-between-qaiss-aria-and-dirk-v).

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Comment: this is what i m seeing there

Answer (score 0):

You have to do signaling which mean that you have to exchange the PEER CONNECTIONS over the server and which required you to build a server page and client page so both  of you can exchange the peer connection.

here is the complete procedure of exchanging the peer connection over the server.

find the heading
**RTCPeerConnection plus servers**
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: yes i have worked on this just read the documentation and try to understand how the pass the peer connection to your client

Comment: do u have any website or application that uses this technology?

Comment: Well I have a project which needs RTC integration. I can outsource the project if u want

Comment: This is a whole complete documentation....very complex to understand for newbie